# NoSuchMethodException when using reflection to get defineClass from ClassLoader

Tags: java, reflection, classloader

I'm trying to use reflection to get the `defineClass` method from ClassLoader

```
ClassLoader cl = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
Method m = cl.getClass().getMethod("defineClass", new Class[] { String.class, Array.class, int.class, int.class });
```

but this fails with a `NoSuchMethodException: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String, java.lang.reflect.Array, int, int)`

It seems plausible that it doesn't like the `Array.class`, but if so, I have no idea what would be required there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ClassLoader.defineClass` takes a `byte` array as its second parameter, not an object of type `Array`. This is what you need:

```
Method m = ClassLoader.class.getDeclaredMethod("defineClass", String.class, byte[].class, int.class, int.class);
```

Comment: Interesting. There's actually two things going on here...in addition to the byte[].class being needed, 

cl.getClass().equals(ClassLoader.class); // false!

Comment: That's because the classloader in question is probably a subclass of ClassLoader. So it's a different class, so I would expect that check to return false!